# How to find an Integrable upper bound for a sequence of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. I need to show $|f_n|$ has an integrable upper bound on $[1,a]$ for some $a>0$. How does one get rid of the $n$’s so that we obtain the Integrable upper bound function independent of $n$?

$$f_n(x)= \frac{n^2+n\sin(nx)}{(n+1)^2x+ n\cos(nx)}$$

Comment: Think about the worst case scenarios for $\sin$ and $\cos$.  The numerator cannot be any larger than $n^2+n$, and the denominator cannot be any less than $(n+1)^2 - n$ (assuming that $a > 1$).  Therefore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $x \in [1,a]$ we have
$$\frac{n^2+n\sin(nx)}{(n+1)^2x + n\cos(nx)} \leq \frac{n^2 + n}{(n+1)^2 - n}.$$
Now since $\frac{n^2 + n}{(n+1)^2 - n}$ converges, it must be a bounded sequence and therefore there must exist a $K$, such that $\frac{n^2 + n}{(n+1)^2 - n} \leq K$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. The constant function $g(x) = K$ is integrable on $[1,a]$.

Comment: More concretely:  $$\frac{n^2+n}{(n+1)^2 - n} = \frac{n^2 + n}{n^2 + n + 1} \le \frac{n^2 + n}{n^2+n} = 1. $$  This bound is sharp, too, as the fraction tends to $1$ as $n \to \infty$.